# How to present a modal component on header component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, header, modal-dialog

I am new in react native.I am having a custom header component and on that created a touchable opacity of orange color ,I want to present a modal component on Press of it.Is it possible to do so in react native.Please suggest some ways on this.

Attached the tried code and screenshot.

```
  <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            openPop();
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: "row",
              alignItems: "center",
              backgroundColor: "orange",
            }}
          >
            {backButton ? (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={backHandler}
                style={{
                  height: moderateScale(30),
                  width: moderateScale(30),
                  justifyContent: "center",
                  alignItems: "center",
                }}
              >
                <Image
                  source={backWhiteIcon}
                  resizeMode="contain"
                  style={{
                    height: moderateScale(30),
                    width: moderateScale(30),
                  }}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ) : (
              <Image
                source={backWhiteIcon}
                resizeMode="contain"
                style={{
                  height: moderateScale(30),
                  width: moderateScale(30),
                }}
              />
            )}

            <View>
              <Text
                style={{
                  marginLeft: moderateScale(8),
                  fontFamily: FONT_FAMILY.regular,
                  fontSize: FONT_SIZE.font_14,
                  fontWeight: FONT_WEIGHT.fontWeight7,
                  lineHeight: moderateScale(19.12),
                  color: titleColor,
                }}
              >
                {title}
              </Text>
              <Text
                style={{
                  marginLeft: moderateScale(8),
                  fontFamily: FONT_FAMILY.regular,
                  fontSize: FONT_SIZE.font_12,
                  fontWeight: FONT_WEIGHT.fontWeight4,
                  lineHeight: moderateScale(16.39),
                  color:"white"
                   
                }}
              >
                P&L
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

and this is onPress function

```
const openPop = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Modal>
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text>I am the modal content!</Text>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

and I want this modal to open onclick of this orange area in image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how the structure of your navigation is implemented. I'm guessing you are using `react-navigation`? If so, a possible solution could be to define your modal in the root of your navigation.

Something like this:

```js
<RootStack.Navigator>
  <RootStack.Group>
    <RootStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
  </RootStack.Group>
  <RootStack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal' }}>
    <RootStack.Screen name="Modal" component={ModalScreen} />
  </RootStack.Group>
</RootStack.Navigator>
```

This way your modal is accesible using `navigation.navigate()`.
So in your header component `onPress`, just call `navigation.navigate('Modal')` to show your modal.

Comment: The only problem I found with this is sometimes you want to use a loading modal. And if you treat it as a route, then you have to create global state for the modal to listen to and store a navigation action inside of it. Seems better to have a screen with a modal and let the screen state turn it on/off. But it won't go over the header unfortunately(at least from what I could find)